# Invariant subspaces of permutation matrix

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra

Let $\sigma$ be a permutation matrix of order $n$. What are all the invariant subspaces of $\sigma$?

(I can only find 1 and n-1 dimensional subspaces)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: By "invariant", do you mean "mapped back to itself"?  If so, since every permutation matrix is semisimple (at least in characteristic 0), then the invariant subspaces are direct sums of one-dimensional invariant subspaces.  So if you know all the one-dimensional invariant subspaces, then you know all the invariant subspaces.

Comment: "the invariant subspaces are direct sums of one-dimensional invariant subspaces" . Is this also true for fields that are not algebraically closed?

Comment: "Is this also true for fields that are not algebraically closed?"  No, my comment was for algebraically closed fields.  Over a non-algebraically closed field, you can try to use Galois descent: the eigenvalues of $\sigma$ are $n^{\text{th}}$ roots of unity.  The Galois group acts on these roots.  For each Galois orbit, the sum over that orbit of the projectors onto the corresponding eigenspaces will be Galois invariant.